# How to implement a Neural Network in C++

Tags: c++, neural-network, backpropagation

### Original question

I am working on a simple C++ library. I'm trying to implement a Neural Network. I've got two questions:

1. Are there any tutorials which explain how they can be implemented?
2. Do I *really* need to plot a graph when I implement the Neural Network?

---

The code that I have written so far is:

```cpp
#ifndef NEURAL_NETWORK_H
#define NEURAL_NETWORK_H

#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

class NeuralNetwork {
    public :
        void SetWeight(double tempWeights [15]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(tempWeights) / sizeof(double)); ++i) {
                weights[i] = tempWeights[i];
            }
        }

        double GetWeights() {
            return weights;
        }

        void Train(int numInputs, int numOutputs, double inputs[], double outputs[]) {
            double tempWeights[numOutputs];

            int iterator = 0;

            while (iterator < 10000) {
                  // This loop will train the Neural Network
            }

            SetWeights(tempWeights);
        }

        double[] Calculate(double inputs[]) {
             // Calculate Outputs...

             return outputs;
        }

        NeuralNetwork(double inputs[], double outputs[]) {
            int numberOfInputs = sizeof(inputs) / sizeof(double);
            int numberOfOutputs = sizeof(outputs) / sizeof(double);

            Train(numberOfInputs, numberOfOutputs, inputs[], outputs[]);
        }
    private :
        double weights[15];
};

#endif // NEURAL_NETWORK_H
```

---

### Edited and updated question

Thanks to the help from the comments, I managed to implement the Neural Network.

Now, I'm currently struggling with a performance issue. `srand` has actually started becoming unhelpful a bit...

Are there better random functions?

Comment: 1) Yes and  2) No.

Comment: Yes, there are better random functions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I learnt a lot about how we think from this project, I learnt about `std::uniform_real_distribution<>`, `std::vector<>` and syntax structure.

`srand` and `time` are C functions. Therefore, for the best optimisation, they should not be used.

So, what should we use? `std::uniform_real_distribution` because it is more flexible and stable.

```cpp
std::vector<double> set_random_weights()
{ 
    std::default_random_engine generator; 
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

    std::vector<double> temp_weights;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (num_input_nodes * num_hidden_nodes); ++i)
    {
        temp_weights.push_back(distribution(generator));
    }

   return temp_weights;
}
```

However to use `std::uniform_real_distribution` and `std::default_random_engine` we need to include the `random` header:

```cpp
#include <random>
```

And to use `std::vector`s, we must in the `vector` header:

```cpp
#include <vector>
```

Comment: "srand and time are C functions. Therefore, for the best optimisation, they should not be used." - this is old and outdated formulation of a problem. both are achieved with hardware since any cpu this days has true random generator. same goes for time, every cpu this days have RTC peripheral which is pretty accurate.